# how can pass javascript variable to twig?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twig

```
var prova= $("select#utente_regione_name").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ path('province', { 'variabile': 'prova<------it's correct?' }) 
}}",
```

Comment: Don't quote the variable name - that makes is a string "prova", not a variable.

Comment: wuaooo thx very muchhhhh!!!! -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access data which comes in array `$_POST` in twig. You should change you script to pass variable from `$_POST` to you twig template.

Comment: i say, can i pass javascript variable to twing??
var "prova"  to  {{ path('province', { 'variabile': 'prova' } }}
it's possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass it as an attribute, like this:

```
var prova= $("select#utente_regione_name").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ path('province') }}",
    data: { variable: prova },
}}",
```

of course that means that in Controller you should read it from

```
$variable = $this->getRequest()->get('variable');
```

and remove that from your route. I don't think it's so crucial to have that parameter in route for Ajax routes.

PS. I would appreciate if somebody will post how to do this in a true Symfony way, because this still looks like workaround for me.

Comment: Look at this :  FOSJsRoutingBundle. With it you can use router from JS:

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { "id": 10, "foo": "bar" });

Comment: I had the same problem and got this to work in a snap with the FOSJsRoutingBundle. @MilesM.: would you also post this a an answer, as it appears to be the most convenient way of solving this type of challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Using FOSJsRoutingBundle will do the job fine. - that's precisely why it has been made for.

With it you can use router from JS:

```
Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { "id": 10, "foo": "bar" });
```